# Algorithm for comparing list elements backwards

Tags: sorting

Input: A list of real numbers $[x_0, ..., x_n]$

Output: A list of integers $[d_0, ... , d_n]$ where $d_i$ is the largest $d\in\{1,\dots,i\}$ such that
$$
x_i\geq x_{i-1}, x_{i-2},\dots,x_{i-d}
$$

In other words, $d_i$ says how far one can go backwards from $x_i$ without finding a larger element in the list.

Question 1: Is there a more compact or understandable way for the precise formulation?

Question 2: What is a good algorithm producing Output from Input?

Comment: Could you share some information about the application of such a problem? 
This question looks like an undergraduate programming exercise, which would not be adequate for cstheory SE ("Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional researchers in theoretical computer science and related fields." https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour). If it is not, sharing some information about where it comes from would motivate your peers to work on it. If it is, maybe you should ask on a more adequate stack exchange channel, like https://cs.stackexchange.com/t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1.

I found the notation a little confusing. The variable $n$ has repeated in two places.

To rephrase the question.

Input: A list of real numbers $[x_0, ..., x_n]$

Output: A list of integers $[d_0, ... , d_n]$ where $d_i$ is the largest $m\in\{1,\dots,i\}$ such that
$$
x_i\geq x_{i-1}, x_{i-2},\dots,x_{i-m}
$$

Part 2.

Using a stack I believe this can be achieved in linear time.

If $input[i] < input[j]$ for any $i < j$, then for any index $i<j<k$ which is trying to update the $output[k]$ the value of $input[i]$ does not matter. If $input[k]>input[j]$ then $input[k]>input[i]$. A stack can maintain this information well.

Below is a pseudo-code for the same.

```
fn compute(input)
  stack = []
  output = []
  for i = 1:n
      while not stack.empty() and stack.top()["value"] < input[i]
        stack.pop()
      end
      if stack.empty()
        output.push(i) # Can go back all the way
      else
        output.push(i-stack.top()["index"]) 
      end
      stack.push([{"index":i, "value":input[i]}]) # Push pair index,value
  end
  return output
end
```